# Use service to run EXE as admin

Tags: windows, service, admin, exe

I had a recent discussion with a friend about the different ways a virus can operate on a computer

During our discussion we talked about the different ways a malicious software can run each start with
 admin privileges if its installed on the computer

one of the ways i know about is using task scheduler to do so

i told him i once read that its possible to run an EXE with an interactive windows service and i wanted to know if an interactive windows service can also run an EXE with admin privileges.

Comment: Why you want to create a virus?

Comment: In XP and below this used to work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This post shows how to get admin privilege through bat file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file . After gaining the privilege you can start an application from the bat file using start command.

Comment: Im trying to understand how i can defend my computer better by understanding how hackers use different methods to take over my system,Cant i ask a security question without people blaming me for trying to create a virus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching an interactive process as administrator from system service running in standard logged in user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098315/launching-an-interactive-process-as-administrator-from-system-service-running-in)