# Starting process on user desktop Windows

Tags: windows, command, system, admin, desktop

Recently while trying things out on Windows admin I came across a situation. For example when I have a system level task scheduled to for example start Windows calculator the task would trigger and start the process.

The problem however is that the process doesn't appear on the current users desktop. I was wondering how one could still using the system account I could start calculator on the current use desktop.

I would prefer this fix be through the command rather than changes to settings for the task as tasks aren't the only situation in which this problem occurs. For example I believe I had the same problem when starting a process using a system level command prompt or when starting a process on a different computer using an admin account and psexec.

I am aware there are risks of using system. This question is mostly how to start a process on a specific desktop or the current user rather than just appearing on task manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launching an administrative interactive process when a standard user is logged on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098315/launching-an-administrative-interactive-process-when-a-standard-user-is-logged-o)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not *entirely* sure I'm clear on the issue... it may be that the "[runas](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)" command-line utility will server your purpose.

Comment: I need to be able to run on whatever user is currently logged in without knowing there username or password. Would the /netonly parameter make this happen?

Comment: You may want to leverage a group policy to manage such a scenario: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725828(v=ws.10).aspx