# C++ windows LocalSystem impersonation in child process failing

Tags: c++, windows, impersonation, localsystem

Trying to resolve it but all efforts are in vain so far. The workflow as follows

Windows service running as LocalSystem creates child using `CreateProcessAsUser(...)` with token of current logged user.

```
const auto session = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
auto result = WTSQueryUserToken(session, &token);

HANDLE primary;
result = DuplicateTokenEx(token,
    TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
    TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
    nullptr, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &primary);

const auto args = std::to_string(reinterpret_cast<long>(access));
CreateProcessAsUser(primary,
                      const_cast<LPSTR>(command.c_str()), // module name
                      const_cast<LPSTR>(args.c_str()),    // Command line
                      nullptr, // Process handle not inheritable
                      nullptr, // Thread handle not inheritable
                      TRUE,    // Set handle inheritance to TRUE
                      0,       // No creation flags
                      nullptr, // Use parent's environment block
                      nullptr, // Use parent's starting directory
                      &si,     // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                      &pi);    // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

The child process is launched in user workstation\desktop and main thread captures user I/O events. The child process impersonation is as follows

```
 void impersonate() {
  const auto args = GetCommandLine();
  const auto system_token = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(std::stol(args, nullptr));

  if (SetThreadToken(nullptr, system_token) == TRUE) {
   auto result = OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(),
                            TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, TRUE, &token);
  if (result == TRUE)
  {
    DWORD dwSize = 0;

   if (!GetTokenInformation(token, TokenStatistics, NULL, 0, &dwSize)) {
      const auto dwResult = GetLastError();

          if (dwResult != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            cout << "GetTokenInformation Error: " << dwResult;

          } else {
          // Allocate the buffer.
            PTOKEN_STATISTICS statistics =
                (PTOKEN_STATISTICS)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwSize);

            // Call GetTokenInformation again to get the group information.
            if (!GetTokenInformation(token, TokenStatistics, statistics, dwSize,
                           &dwSize)) {
              cout << "GetTokenInformation Error: " << error;
            } else {
              const auto level = statistics->ImpersonationLevel;
              std::string str;

              switch (level) {
              case SecurityAnonymous:
                str = R"(anonymous)";
                break;
              case SecurityIdentification:
                str = R"(identification)";
                break;
              case SecurityImpersonation:
                str = R"(impersonation)";
                break;
              case SecurityDelegation:
                str = R"(delegation)";
                break;
              }

              // This outputs identification.
              cout << "impersonation level : " << str;  
          }
      }
   }
 }

void thread_main() 
{
   impersonate();

   // if impersonation is successful, file opening fails otherwise not.
   const auto file = CreateFile(R"(C:\foo.txt)",                // name of the write
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL);                  // no attr. template

  if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

  } else {
    // Rest of code;
  }
}
```

Though current user is Administrator and added "Impersonate a Client After authentication" it still reporting "Security Identification".

**Q:** Is there anything else required to raise it to Security impersonate?
Thanks,

Comment: you not show code - how you impersonate, but i assume that your child process have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` - as result `SetThreadToken` ok, but `ImpersonationLevel` is set to  **Identification**. for check this - call `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenStatistics` and check `TOKEN_STATISTICS.ImpersonationLevel`

Comment: @RbMm I added more information as per suggested findings.

Comment: from your code - unclear how you impersonate.

Comment: you need open **thread** token - not process token. all info which you paste - irrelevant. you need show - how you impersonate and **thread** token *ImpersonationLevel*

Comment: @RbMm I have added impersonate method, thats all what child thread is  impersonating.

Comment: so - was exactly as I guess at begin - "Security Identification". your process have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` and your user not admin really. as result in call `SetThreadToken` - the `ImpersonationLevel` in token downgraded from impersonation to identification. with this impersonation level - all security checks will fail

Comment: You guessed it right. Is there any way that standard user process can be elevated or impersonated?

Comment: this is special (disable impersonation and elevation) by design. so way exist only as "exploit"

Comment: Presumably you're duplicating a handle to `system_token` from the parent to the child; if the only purpose of the impersonation is to write the file, consider duplicating a file handle rather than a token handle.  Or you could run the child process as local system and have it impersonate the user rather than the other way around.

Comment: @HarryJohnston 
purpose of impersonation is privilege so standard users can't not write/modified application objects and application can execute system privileged tasks like other process information etc. The process can't be created using CreateProcess as it should in logged on user session [Winsta0\default-desktop] so it capture user keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: @jeeran - really exist solution, by create child process with elevated user token (not restricted) - after call `WTSQueryUserToken` need get `TokenLinkedToken` (if you have `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` - but service have if run as *LocalSystem*). i now update self answer

Comment: You can create a process that runs as local system in the user's session.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21127414/886887

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, this is possible solution, if not need access say `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, current user profile, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how I understand you do next - you duplicate *LocalSystem* token, from service, to child process (via inherit handle) and pass it handle value in command line. then you call [`SetThreadToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590(v=vs.85).aspx).

but documentation of [`SetThreadToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590(v=vs.85).aspx) is wrong and incomplete.

here only said that token must have `TOKEN_IMPERSONATE` access rights. 
nothing said about Thread handle access rights - it must have `THREAD_SET_THREAD_TOKEN`

but main:

> When using the **SetThreadToken** function to impersonate, you must
>   have the ***impersonate privileges*** and make sure that the
>   **SetThreadToken** function succeeds

what is mean under **you must have** ? usually this mean that calling thread (or process to which calling thread belong in case thread have no token) must have impersonate privileges in token.

but this is wrong and not true. which privilege you ( calling thread ) have - does not matter. the process (*even if target thread have token*) to which target (not calling !) thread belong must have `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privilege or have the same logon session id as impersonation token, otherwise .. no, function not fail, and return succeeds, but it silently replace [`SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379572(v=vs.85).aspx) member in token to `SecurityIdentification` (look in *WRK-v1.2\base\ntos\ps\security.c* `PsImpersonateClient` function - begin from `SeTokenCanImpersonate` (implemented in *WRK-v1.2\base\ntos\se\token.c* - here and checked `TOKEN_HAS_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE` and LogonSessionId) and if fail (`STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`) returned by `SeTokenCanImpersonate` - the `PsImpersonateClient` function set `ImpersonationLevel = SecurityIdentification ;`

so even if you call `SetThreadToken` from service (which have impersonation privilege) for child process thread - call is "fail" if child process have not impersonation privilege. and visa versa - if you say pass(duplicate) own thread handle (with `THREAD_SET_THREAD_TOKEN` access rights) to restricted process, which have not impersonation privilege - he can success call `SetThreadToken` for **your** thread - impersonation level will be not reset to `SecurityIdentification`

in your case, because child process have no `SeImpersonatePrivilege` (usually it exist only in elevated processes, but if user enter to system with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` - even "admins" have really restricted token (so they not really true admins)) and have different session id (compare local system token session id) - after `SetThreadToken` your thread have `SecurityIdentification` impersonation level. as result any system call, where security checked (say open file or registry key) will fail with error `ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`.

how about solution ? **if user have admin privileges** - you need create **elevated** child process in user session (like "run as admin" ). for this you need query elevation type of token returned by `WTSQueryUserToken` and if it is [`TokenElevationTypeLimited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530718(v=vs.85).aspx) - we need get [linked token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530719(v=vs.85).aspx) by `GetTokenInformation` call with [`TokenLinkedToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx).

this is complete undocumented, but which token returned in [`TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530719(v=vs.85).aspx) structure depend from are **calling** thread (or process) have `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` - if yes - [`TokenPrimary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379633(v=vs.85).aspx) is returned. otherwise [`TokenImpersonation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379633(v=vs.85).aspx) is returned with [`SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379572(v=vs.85).aspx) set to `SecurityIdentification` (so this token can be used only for query). because service running under Local system account have `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` - you got the primary token, which you need use in `CreateProcessAsUser` call as is. so you need next function:

```
ULONG GetElevatedUserToken(PHANDLE phToken)
{
    union {
        ULONG SessionId;
        TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tet;
        TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN tlt;
        TOKEN_TYPE tt;
    };

    SessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    if (SessionId == MAXDWORD)
    {
        return ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION;
    }

    HANDLE hToken;

    if (!WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId, &hToken))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG len;

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevationType, &tet, sizeof(tet), &len))
    {
        if (tet == TokenElevationTypeLimited)
        {
            if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, &tlt, sizeof(tlt), &len))
            {
                CloseHandle(hToken);
                hToken = tlt.LinkedToken;
            }
            else
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    if (dwError == NOERROR)
    {
        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenType, &tt, sizeof(tt), &len))
        {
            if (tt != TokenPrimary)
            {
                dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        if (dwError == NOERROR)
        {
            *phToken = hToken;
            return NOERROR;
        }

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

and use next code for start child

```
HANDLE hToken;

ULONG dwError = GetElevatedUserToken(&hToken);

if (dwError == NOERROR)
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    //***
    if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, ***, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

in this case you may be not need at all impersonate to *LocalSystem* in child process. however if still need *LocalSystem* - you can duplicate such token in child process and in this case `SetThreadtoken` will be full ok, because child process will be have impersonate privileges

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work if the logged-on user has administrator privilege.  Whether or not that is a problem depends on the intended use.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, you right. i forget clear say, that user need have potential administrator privileges. unfortunately, by design, we can not use impersonation on thread from restricted process. even if we try do this from local system process or even from kernel mode

Comment: I guess that if you *could* do that, the outcome would be a thread with administrative privilege that a non-privileged user has complete control over.  So it makes sense that it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for asking what should be obvious but it needs to be asked:

Are you checking the return values of these functions?  Calling GetLastError when they fail?  What error codes are you getting back?

If this is C++ are you setting an unhandled exception handler?

Comment: I handled all error codes,  `CreateFile` is crashing application though file exists and contents can be read if I commented out impersonation method.

Comment: Fair enough.  Next step is Win32 SetUnhandledExceptionFilter wrapping the CreateFile call.   That should catch the "crash" live and give you enough info to at least dump it out out somewhere...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit:  I should say a structured exception try block around the CreateFile call but you should have an unhandled exception filter already set up.  Note that I am assuming you are *not* using C++ exceptions here.  You cannot mix C++ and structured exceptions in the same function.